# Conditional Array Decleration

Tags: java, arrays

I'd like to declare an array of a specific size depending on a condition, but Eclipse gives me an error. This is my if condition:

> ```
>   if ( (a.length == b.length) && (a[maxlength - 1] + b[maxlength - 1] >= 10))
>         int[] c = new int[maxlength + 1];
>     else
>         int[] c = new int[maxlength];
> ```

I get the following errors on the lines of both array declarations:

- "c cannot be resolved to a variable"
- "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

Why does this not work? Are there alternative ways of achieving the same goal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to block-level scoping. `c` is only known inside the scope of the block. So `c` is known inside the `if` block and the `else` block, but also keep in mind that the `c` inside the `if` and the `c` inside the `else` are different. Once control exits either of the blocks (since it can only be in one of them at any time), the reference to `c` is lost.

If you want `c` to be available outside the blocks, it should be declared outside:

```
int[] c;
if ( (a.length == b.length) && (a[maxlength - 1] + b[maxlength - 1] >= 10)) {
       c = new int[maxlength + 1];
} else {
       c = new int[maxlength];
}
```

I also recommend using braces in your `if` and `else` because otherwise only the succeeding statement is executed, which can lead to subtle bugs if you are not careful.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
int[] c;
if ( (a.length == b.length) && (a[maxlength - 1] + b[maxlength - 1] >= 10))
    c = new int[maxlength + 1];
else
    c = new int[maxlength];
```

Then you can use `c`.